# int wrapper without overloading all the operators

Tags: c++

I would like to have an `int` wrapper class that behaves like `int` without the need to overload all of the operators. The same question was asked but not really answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643893/transparent-c-number-int-wrapper). I know I can write a template wrapper and overload dozens of operators to achieve that (in fact, I have it like that now - [basically it looks like this mess](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f5566f15c11c52e2db7189d602cc601a-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)). However it would be nice if it would be possible to somehow expose the internal primitive type without the need to overload the operators that just forward the call to it.

Is that possible? Perhaps by overloading dereferencing operators or somesuch?

EDIT: Example code:

```
template<typename T>

class IDWrapper
{
public:
    inline IDWrapper() { }
    inline IDWrapper(T id) : m_Value(id) {  }

    constexpr static int size() { return sizeof(T); }
    constexpr static T min() { return std::numeric_limits<T>::min(); }
    constexpr static T max() {  return std::numeric_limits<T>::max(); }

    inline bool isValid() const { return m_Value != 0; }
    inline operator T() const { return m_Value; }
    inline operator T&() { return m_Value; } //this line was the attempt to make it transparent... unsuccessfully
    inline IDWrapper &operator=(T v) { m_Value = v; return *this; }
    inline void invalidate() { m_Value = 0; }

private:
    T m_Value = 0;
};
```

Basically it wraps an ID of type `T` in a "special" way so that it gives convenient options for validating and invalidating it. Plus it gives convenient access the the size and min/max. The reason for the templated wrapper is that I will need to replace it later with base64 number or some other non-standard number type and I need the interface that relies on the IDWrapper to stay consistent. The numerical operators will still be provided by `T` so when I spell them out here I am just forwarding the call hence the question.

Comment: Overload the conversion operator?

Comment: Good question, but it would be easier if you just in-lined the relevant part of example code into your post.

Comment: This is a rough use case of a dot operator overload, but that's not going to be in C++ until at least the dialect after C++17. Given that this is a simple `int` wrapper, perhaps `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` can help, but last I remember, its author had some design problems with it.

Comment: What's the background for doing this?  Since there are already big number or big integer libraries in existence.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have added my use case (hopefully understandable).

Comment: Are you okay with an implicit conversion to type `T`? If so, implement `operator T() const { return mValue; }`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison I am and I have (see the code in the EDIT of the OP) but it does not work. Plus I need to be able to modify the value as well (hence my implicit operator T&() but that does not work either. For example call to  operator++ does nothing because it invokes operator T() const hence it happens on the copy...

Comment: @JamesAdkison Although having operator const T&() const AND operator T&() could actually work... hm.

Comment: Have you considered using boost's strong typedef instead of your own custom rolled ID class? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html

Comment: @MarkB I have, it would require for defininition of the boost strong typedef and inheriting from it. Since my solution (below) is exactly the same (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/boost/strong_typedef.hpp) as boost strong typedef I don't think it is worthwhile to add boost as dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have fiddled with it inspired by the comments to the OP and it seems that having these two (and only these two) overloaded operators can do the trick:

```
operator T&() { /*...*/ }
operator const T&() const { /*...*/ }
```

Naturally it is not without the cost. For example if `T` is an `int` (or any type for which `sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*)`) then returning const reference to it is more expensive than doing a copy (but having a copy operator breaks the transparency). Not to mention memory address lookup. I am not sure about potential other problems with this so feel free to comment/answer. But this works.

Comment: define "works". what do you want to support? what are your test-cases?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I want to support a wrapper class for T that does not overload all of the operators (that would just forward them to T) yet the execution of these operators is done on the wrapped type directly. The explanation is in OP but basically I want to have some custom/convenient methods added atop of the T with the class otherwise behaving - being - T. And since you cannot inherit from primitive type the wrapper is the answer.

Comment: example: what's the result of adding two IDWrappers?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Just tested it. If added to one of them then the left operand becomes the sum of its original value and the value of the right operand. If the result of the operation is assigned to another IDWrapper then also the sum of the two (with the third value assigned to being overwritten) and both operands remain untouched (as expected).

Comment: @Resurrection I *think* the question was "what is the physical meaning of adding two id numbers?"

Comment: @MarkB In that case the meaning stems from the fact that IDWrapper is a sequential ID class with generic internal type (integer of some sort) so adding two IDs together will produce ID that is in the position in the sequence equal to the sum of the constituents' positions.